# Are conflicting matching embedded interface methods a feature, bug or other?

Tags: go, interface

I've run into this a few times and its easy to work around but I'm just wondering if there are any advantages to the Go compiler complaining when interfaces embed interfaces with matching method signatures.

For example, if I want a few variations on a logger going to different packages but ultimately I want to use the same logger I might try something like this:

```
type Logger interface {
    Print(v ...interface{})
    Printf(format string, v ...interface{})
}

type DebugLogger interface {
    Logger
    Debug(v ...interface{})
    Debugf(format string, v ...interface{})
}

type ErrorLogger interface {
    Logger
    Error(v ...interface{})
    Errorf(format string, v ...interface{})
}

type ErrorDebugLogger interface {
    ErrorLogger
    DebugLogger
}

type ErrorDebugLoggerImp struct{}
func (l *ErrorDebugLoggerImp) Debug(v ...interface{})                 {}
func (l *ErrorDebugLoggerImp) Debugf(format string, v ...interface{}) {}
func (l *ErrorDebugLoggerImp) Error(v ...interface{})                 {}
func (l *ErrorDebugLoggerImp) Errorf(format string, v ...interface{}) {}
func (l *ErrorDebugLoggerImp) Print(v ...interface{})                 {}
func (l *ErrorDebugLoggerImp) Printf(format string, v ...interface{}) {}
```

and this could be used as a param to the following methods:

```
func p1.RegisterLogger(l Logger){}

func p2.RegisterLogger(l DebugLogger){}

func p3.RegisterLogger(l ErrorLogger){}

func p4.RegisterLogger(l DebugErrorLogger){}
```

But this won't work because the compiler will complain that ErrorDebugLogger has duplicate methods. It seems to me that this would be fairly trivial for the compiler to resolve the fact that these methods are identical and there is no conflict and this would make these kind of patterns simpler.

Here the solution is trivial but results in some duplication which gets worse if trying to wrap interfaces from external packages.

Is there any down side to allowing this kind of duplication when embedding interfaces, perhaps I am underestimating the complexity for the compiler?

**UPDATE**
Most of the comments seemed to miss the fact that all I had provided were interfaces (maybe Im still missing something), implementation now included with example usage for clarity

Comment: When you call Logger's methods from ErrorDebugLogger the compiler has now way of knowing which Logger implementation you want, the one embedded in ErrorLogger or the one in DebugLogger.

Comment: but when they are matching signatures it doesn't matter, since any implementation would satisfy both

Comment: Sure you could say, hey let's have the runtime execute the first one that matches, but that seems, at least to me, against the explicit nature of Go.

Comment: Just because the signatures match doesn't mean you would have the same implementation in both `ErrorLogger` and `DebugLogger`.

Comment: so I would say the compiler should not just take the first but actively confirm that the signature match, @Gavin There is no implementation embedded in an interface though, in cases like this the implementation would be the same but that is always for consumer to determine surely

Comment: @SwiftD `that is always for consumer to determine surely` Right, and as mkopriva has pointed out, how is the compiler supposed to know which implementation to call at runtime? It can't ask the consumer. Personally, I feel like a better approach would be to remove the embedded `Logger` from the `DebugLogger` and `ErrorLogger`, and embed the aforementioned with `Logger` in your `ErrorDebugLogger`. That seems to align a little more with the stdlib in regards to interfaces like `io.Reader`, `io.ReadCloser`, etc. Although, the design decision is ultimately up to you.

Comment: im definitely missing something here: "how is the compiler supposed to know which implementation to call at runtime" which ever implementation is provided to satisfy the entire interface - there is only ever one implementation matching multiple interfaces, the compiler has no choice to make

Comment: @Flimzy well thats a point but wouldn't that apply whenever you embed a third party interface - if they change it suddenly then things break yes, at that point i would expect compiler to complain signatures don't match or x no longer satisfies the interface

Comment: @SwiftD `ErrorDebugLogger` can have two different instances of `Logger`, one through each of its embedded interface types. Remember, this is composition, not inheritance.

Comment: @Gavin Still not getting it, an interface is not an implementation of anything, I have included a single implementation that satisfies all the interfaces to clarify. If the methods in the embedded interfaces are the  same I still do not see any confusion for the compiler - ErrorDebugLoggerImp should now satisfy any of the above interfaces and indeed if I remove the embedded Logger from either DebugLogger or ErrorLogger it does. But that makes one of those useless in my use case

Comment: @Gavin I kind of get your point that this is embedding not inheritance and perhaps that is what it comes down to but I just cant see why the compiler couldn't resolve that there is no conflict when embedding the same method signature twice, hopefully updated example illustrates the advantage

Comment: Also re. removing Logger from DebugLogger and ErrorLogger - the idea is that methods that require those interfaces require the Print funcs in Logger as well. The only solution is to duplicate the Print funcs in both interfaces

Comment: @SwiftD I've missed the point completely initially and I see your issue now. Unfortunately for you that's how the compiler is implemented and a question about the reasons behind that implementation would be more suitable for the go-nuts mailing list. Also take a look at https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6977

Comment: Yes, you may be dealing with interfaces, but you ultimately need to have an implementation of that interface to use it. The example is nasty, but it may explain your problem here a little better. https://gist.github.com/gavinwade12/aa736b98434f0f585049e27d5e267b63

Comment: @mkopriva that issue seems to reference exactly the same issue and I think that answers my question - i would be happy to accept that issue reference as an answer as to the current state of affairs if you would present as an answer

Comment: @Gavin that's not what I was attempting to describe - you have pointed out an issue with embedding types (e.g structs) with the same method, i have no issue with how things work there - i am talking about embedding interfaces only - I think they probably explain it better in the link mkopriva provided if you are interested (although similar confusion in that thread too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been discussed here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6977

There's also a question here on SO about *how to address* the issue, maybe you'll find the answer useful: [How to deal with duplicate methods in Go interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730255/how-to-deal-with-duplicate-methods-in-go-interface)

Comment: If anyone is looking at this now - it appears that this is now allowed in the latest golang release. See referenced issue for details